# Mysql database to Nosql hbase using java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hbase, nosql

I want to convert this relation-ship "1 to many" Employees can have 0 or many Orders to Nosql hbase 
[image: Mysql data base]

Answer (score 1):

In the case of HBase to retrieve all orders for one employee you can have following structure for row key:

```
RowRey = ShardKey + EmployeeID + OrderID
```

where `ShardKey` is (EmployeeID % number of regions). This allows to efficiently distribute data between regions servers to avoid hot-spotting. You can have two column family. In the first column family columns of the row can be same as in Order table. In the second column will be same as in Employee table. Since these data have different update rate it is suggested to keep them separately.

> A column family is an HBase-specific concept that you will not find in other RDBMS applications. For the same region, different column families will store the data into different files and can be configured differently. Data with the same access pattern and the same format should be grouped into the same column family. As an example regarding the format, if you need to store a lot of textual metadata information for customer profiles in addition to image files for each customer’s profile photo, you might want to store them into two different column families: one compressed (where all the textual information will be stored), and one not compressed (where the image files will be stored). As an example regarding the access pattern, if some information is mostly read and almost never written, and some is mostly written and almost never read, you might want to separate them into two different column families. If the different columns you want to store have a similar format and access pattern, regroup them within the same column family.

But to keep it simple you can save Employee data in separate table with following row key

```
RowRey = ShardKey + EmployeeID
```

[Architecting HBase Applications](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035688.do)